# Lissajous figure PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, figure

I have a lissajous figure write in PHP but i want to dynamically change a1,a2 T1,T2 value by implementing a zip. Can someone help me to do that? Here is a similar example of what I mean

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/06/dependency-property-performance-and-lissajous-figures/

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 header ("Content-type: image/png");
///x = a1 * cos(t/T1);
/// y = a2 * sin(t/T2);
$T1 = 20;
$T2 = 30;

$myImage = @imagecreatetruecolor(640, 480)
       or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($myImage, 255, 255, 224);
$poly_color = imagecolorallocate($myImage, 124, 120, 224);

//calculate x-value and y-value point by point
$points = array();
 for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i=$i+1)
 {
     //define curve's function
     $x = 310*cos($i/$T1); //define x-value
     $y = 230*sin($i/$T2);//define y-value

     //move the coordinate, append a point's x-value and y-value
     $points[] = 320+$x; //x-value
     $points[] = 240-$y;  //y-value
}

//count points
$totalPoints = count($points)/2;

//drawing title
$title = "Final Plot ($totalPoints points)";
imagestring($myImage, 3, 5, 5,  $title, $text_color);

/** drawing points one by one, notice if there 
  * are 10 points, we need to draw 9 lines: 
  * 1) point 0 to 1; 
  * 2) point 1 to 2;
  * ...
  * ...
  * 9) point 8 to 9; 
  */
for ($i=0; $i<$totalPoints-1; $i++)
 {
     imageLine($myImage, $points[2*$i], $points[1+2*$i], $points[2+2*$i], $points[3+2*$i], $poly_color);    
 }

//finalizing
imagepng($myImage);
imagedestroy($myImage);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'implementing a zip'?

Comment: Look at example to understand what i mean

Comment: I did, still dont understand what you mean...

Comment: Unless you mean 'controls' that dynamically change the values....which in that case, you'll have to use Javascript not PHP

Comment: Yes, that ecscally what i mean ;p

Comment: Well if you do it in php, it wont be 'realtime' like that example though.  It will be a slider, that when released, posts to the server, updates the values and recreates the image.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes yes ;) I just post an example to give a look what i want to do  ;))

Comment: Im going to bed now, but if this isn't answered by tomorrow morning, I will provide you an answer...

Comment: Well, do you figure something out? ;p

Answer (score 0):

Well....you can start with simple text inputs at first...
Add this as html to the bottom of that file....

```
<form id="yourform" action="" method="post">
 <input name="t1" type="text"/>
  <input name="t2" type="text"/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

then at the top of the file....

```
 If(isset($_POST)){
 $T1 = $_POST['t1'];
 $T2 = $_POST['t2'];} else {
 $T1=20; $T2=30;}
```

Now you can enter in values into the text boxes and pass them to the image for processing.
you can then use JQuery ui to change those inputs to sliders.

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax

Also you can do some validation so as to only allow integers.
But im not gonna do that here...

Hopefully this is enough to get you started :)

Comment: Ill post more when i get home.....im on my ipad right now so typing isnt too easy :)